# How to display all projects and all issues inside each project

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

First off, I am new to Jira development, with that said I am trying to build a simple Jira plugin to display all projects and all issues inside each project. I am able to successfully display all projects directly from a velocity template like this:

```
<div class="aui-group">
    #foreach ( $project in $projectManager.getProjectObjects() )
        <div class="aui-item">
            <h4>$project.getName() - $project.getId()            <span>$projectManager.getCurrentCounterForProject($project.getId())</span></h4>
        </div>
    #end
</div>
```

However, I don't see anything in the documentation to get all issues inside a given project from the ProjectManager interface.
[ProjectManager Docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.2.2/com/atlassian/jira/project/ProjectManager.html#convertToProjectObjects-java.util.Collection-)

I would expect something like

```
$project.getIsses()
```

I do see under [IssueManager interface documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.2.2/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueManager.html) `getIssueIdsForProject()` So does this means that there is no easy way to get all issues on a given project from a velocity template, that I would have to create an endpoint to retrieve this using IssueManager interface by passing each project id as I loop? Please help. Code samples are welcome, as I mentioned I am new to Jira development and my Java is really rusty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not aware there is Rest API which I can leverage from the javascript :)

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-software/REST/cloud/

So I did this:

```
AJS.$.ajax({
    url: "/jira/rest/api/2/project",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (projects) {
        AJS.$.each(projects, function (index, project) {
            getProjectIssues(project);
        });
    }
});

var getProjectIssues = function (project) {
    var pKey = project.key;
    AJS.$.ajax({
        url: "/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=project=" + pKey,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (results) {
            console.log('results ', results);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run a JQL query to get issues related to a known project. You can get JSON output which will allow you to do some post-processing, but there does not appear to be a simple way of getting this information without using the API or JQL.